# Patricia trie node structure for performance and low-memory

Tags: java, oop, memory, trie

For some time I have been trying to implement a `Patricia` like `Trie`. I am having a hard time to choose between two `Node` structures and I am not sure which will be the most performance and memory efficient.

One would be to include two classes, `Node` and `Edge`.

```
public interface Edge {
    long getPath();

    byte getLength();

    Node getChild();
}

public interface Node {
    Edge getRightEdge();

    Edge getLeftEdge();
}
```

The other will have only `Node` ontology. Something like the following:

```
public interface Node {
    Node getLeftChild();
    Node getRightChild();
    
    byte getLeftLength();
    byte getRightLength();
    long getLeftPath();
    long getReftPath();
}
```

My dilemma is the following: the second one seems much more memory efficient if we also take java object `header` and `padding` into account. On the contrary, from my point of view, the first one will be more readable and I think also performant but not sure. So what schema do you think is better?

Any help will be much appreciated.

I have not yet implemented the Trie a lot so that's why the provided code is abstract. So apologies.

Comment: ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: @Turing85 I liked your comment a lot. So i should i go ahead and implement the thing without overthinking? Or did i get that one wrong?

Comment: No, you did get that right. Implement it in the simple way, then check whether you have performance bottlenecks. Only then should you start optimizing.

Comment: Well you helped me a lot, thanks. Not only for this case but in general :)

Comment: Further, don't use `byte` for length, which requires messy casting. Just use `int`. Later when everything is working you might consider optimisations like this, but you sacrifice readability for performance. At the start you need readability above all else so you can debug and understand your code to get it *working*. Working code beats high performance buggy code every time.